# Julia Standalone program interacting in a terminal or Console

Tags: terminal, console, julia

I begin to learn Julia on Windows and I would like to write and compile standalone executable programs working in a Console or Terminal. How may I do that ?

I have installed on Windows Julia 1.0 which works as an evaluation loop in a terminal.

Comment: It depends what you mean. If you mean a standalone executable in the sense that it should not rely at all on a julia installation in the target machine, then this is not something typical and you'd probably be looking at linking julia libraries in C++ code or something.  If instead you're asking how to write and run a standalone script that is run using the julia engine, this is fairly easy to do.

Comment: Oh the second version would be perfect. I just want to have the whole Console available and to be able to write where I need on it, eventualy using escape parameters.

Comment: Please see the [introduction in the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/getting-started/#man-getting-started-1), it covers running scripts well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I use the Geany editor in which I write the Julia program, then I use the command "D:\APPLICATIONS\Julia-1.0.0\bin\julia  %f" and then program execution appears in a standalone terminal (command window). Glad to start the use of this apparently nice and efficient langage.

Comment: [This](https://benlauwens.github.io/ThinkJulia.jl/latest/book.html#_preface) is a good place to start